# display column data in each table data

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Quantity  |   Unit  |  Detials of Items |  ISSUED DATE  |  RETURNED |
          |         |                   |               |           |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
tbl col 1 |tbl col2 | tbl col2          |  tbl col 3    | tbl col4  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

say I have a table in the database that has 4 columns

and that is the table in my website

how would i display my table column data in each table data?

any suggestion please

I only have this codes so far as I am new to php i just use macromedia for the interface

```
$myServer = "server";
 $myUser = "user";
 $myPass = "password";
 $myDB = "mssqldb"; 

 //connection to the database
 $dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
     or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

 //select a database to work with
      $selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
          or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

 //declare the SQL statement that will query the database
     $query = "SELECT eidnumber ";
     $query .= "FROM tablename ";

<table width="935" height="102" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th width="89" rowspan="2" scope="col">Quantity</th>
        <th width="87" rowspan="2" scope="col">Unit</th>
        <th width="137" rowspan="2" scope="col">Details of Item(s) Accounted </th>
        <th width="221" rowspan="2" scope="col">ISSUED DATE </th>
        <th height="51" colspan="3" scope="col">RETURNED</th>
        <th width="254" rowspan="2" scope="col">
    <p>REMARKS</p>    </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th width="24" height="39" scope="col">C</th>
        <th width="18" scope="col">X</th>
        <th width="53" scope="col">DATE</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="935" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="86">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="137">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="221">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="24">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="17">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="253">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="86">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="137">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="221">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="24">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="17">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="253">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="86">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="137">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="221">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="24">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="17">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="253">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="86">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="137">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="221">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="24">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="17">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="253">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="86">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="137">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="221">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="24">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="17">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="253">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="86">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="137">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="221">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="24">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="17">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="253">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="86">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="137">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="221">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="24">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="17">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="253">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="86">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="137">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="221">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="24">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="17">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="253">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="86">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="137">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="221">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="24">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="17">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="253">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="86">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="137">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="221">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="24">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="17">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="253">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="86">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="137">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="221">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="24">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="17">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="253">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="86">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="137">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="221">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="24">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="17">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="253">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="86">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="137">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="221">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="24">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="17">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="253">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="86">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="137">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="221">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="24">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="17">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="253">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="90">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="86">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="137">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="221">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="24">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="17">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="55">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="253">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: well im not a php master, but what i think you should do is that create a for loop in php and add `<td>` in it, and then pull each data from the db.

Comment: @HmxaMughal will do try sir thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), which is a better approach:

```
echo "<table>";
$sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE");
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>". $row['quantity'] ."</td>
        <td>". $row['unit'] ."</td>
        <td>". $row['details'] ."</td>
        <td>". $row['issued_date'] ."</td>
        <td>". $row['returned'] ."</td>
    </tr>
    ";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Or if you're `mysql_` functions, which are deprecated:

```
echo "<table>";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>". $row['quantity'] ."</td>
        <td>". $row['unit'] ."</td>
        <td>". $row['details'] ."</td>
        <td>". $row['issued_date'] ."</td>
        <td>". $row['returned'] ."</td>
    </tr>
    ";
}
echo "/<table>";
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above answer, you can also use mysqli. Here's an example:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->quantity . "</td>"
...etc...
}
```